# Questions having you have vs you had

Tags: conditionals

when asking the question, someone says you **had** vs you **have**.
what is the difference between these.

> What **would** you do if you **had** one year free.

> What **will** you do if you **have** one year free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "if" questions, English pairs a verb in the conditional mood (**would do**) with a verb in the past tense (**had**).

A verb in the present or future tense (**will do**) is paired with a verb in the presesnt tense (**have**).

In the first example, the past-tense verb expresses a hypothetical, with an implication that it's unlikely. Many other languages would use the subjunctive mood here, but English doesn't have subjunctive conjugations (anymore); we just use the simple past.

In the second example, the present-tense verb is an immediate possibility, a practical consideration, not a daydream.

Now grammatically, the likelihood of the precondition (having a year free) isn't really important. I mention that nuance because it tends to inform how you'd construct the sentence.

The rule is that if you use **would**, it's paired with the past tense. If you use **will**, it's paired with the present.